# Ошибка ввода или изменения имени столбца Datagridview

Tags: datagridview

В моем проекте есть 3 формы с Datagridview, во всех есть столбец с именем selected.

Добавляю новую форму с Datagridview, в коллекции Columns добавляю столбцы, в том числе хочу добавить столбец с именем selected, чтобы к нему обращаться по имени из уже работающих процедур.
Но при задании или изменении имени выдается ошибка: Имя уже используется другим компонентом. Приходится обращаться по индексу и переделывать процедуры. Такая же ошибка с несколькими столбцами этого грида.
Уважаемые гуру, подскажите, пожалуйста, как избавиться от этой ошибки?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему. В эту форму Datagridview я скопировал из другой формы, видимо в копии сохранились какие то ссылки из той формы.
Создал новую форму, добавил в нее Datagridview  из панели элементов, добавил вручную все столбцы с нужными именами и все ОК!